# conditional binary operator expected error when the file is empty in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i have a file called MYNAME in path /root/user/
which has some value say SSS_14_10_1992

when the values exists in file the below code works fine
**but when the file is empty , then the below mentioned error is thrown**

i am reading this value from file and matching it wildcard and doing something , when the file has some value the below code works fine , when the file is empty then i am getting conditional error

Below is my code

```
var=$(cat /root/user/MYNAME)

echo $var

su - uname<<!
pwd

if  [ -z "$var" ]; then
   echo "NAME SHOULD BE PROVIDED IN MYNAME FILE"
else
   if [[ $var == SSS_14_10* ]]
     then
     echo "value is matched"
   else
     echo "value has not matched"
   fi
fi
!
```

when the file is empty
i am getting the below error:

```
: conditional binary operator expected
: syntax error near `SSS_14_10*'
: `   if [[  == SSS_14_10* ]]'
```

Comment: Try putting `var=$(cat /root/user/MYNAME)` after `su`. Not sure if the variables defined for one user would withstand a `su` command. I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Also you could replace the assignment using `var=$(</root/user/MYNAME)`

Comment: are you trying to "match" when the right-hand-side expression is `SSS_14_10*` (the `*`)? Use `=~` instead. (or is it `~=`?) . Good luck.

Comment: @sjsam thanks for the reply if i put it inside su it's throwing error like to  put that  outside subshell

Comment: @shelter thanks for the reply , as u side i am trying to do match with wildcard on right hand side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't generate code dynamically like this. Pass the value of `$var` as a parameter to the script run by `su`.

```
var=$(cat /root/user/MYNAME)

echo "$var"

su - uname<<'!' "$var"
pwd

if  [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "NAME SHOULD BE PROVIDED IN MYNAME FILE"
elif [[ $1 == SSS_14_10* ]]; then
   echo "value is matched"
else
   echo "value has not matched"
fi
!
```

Note the single quotes around the here-doc delimiter; this ensures the here document is seen as-is by `su`, so that nothing further needs escaping.

Answer (score 3):

Try to compare `"$var"` (with quotes) instead of `$var` (without quotes).  This way if the variable is empty you're just comparing `""`.